# Passing jinja variable to external JS

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

Sorry if duplicate. But couldn't find it, besides doing some workaround calling functions etc. Is there any straight forward method nowadays? If so, how to do that? Thanks!

It works normally if I use {{ var }} inside the script tag in html, but if I import the js file, it won't work.

Comment: Could you please give a reproducible example of this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a script tag to define the jinja variable, then import your external JS after the script tag.

`html`

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <script>
    const myJinjaVar = {{ var }};
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="externalJs.js"></script>
</body>
```

`externalJs.js`

```js
console.log(myJinjaVar); // uses var defined in template
```

Comment: Thanks! I got a similar answer on discord. It used query on a hidden element, and inside the element was the Jinja variable as a text